# Which method is correct in integration?

Tags: integration

I have solved this integration question with two methods. I just want to know that which method is correct and why?
As integration is reverse of derivation so when I try to differentiate both answers I get different functions. It[image] must be same though.

Comment: Those functions look the same to me.  What makes you think they are different?

Comment: @lulu +1 The only difference is that the constants of integration, which are unfortunately both called $C$, differ by $125/6$.

Comment: The only difference between two expressions is that the left one has one more summand $\;\frac{(-5)^3}6\;$ , but as indefinite integrals (or in its more accurate, and more and more widely used name: antiderivatives) is determined only up to a constant summand, both are correct.

Comment: Should get the same upon differentiation. Check your work.

Answer (score 2):

Expand the cube of the "left-side method" to see they are in fact the same; mind the constant of integration though.

---

Simpler example; on the one hand you have:
$$\int x+1 \,\mbox{d}x = \frac{(x+1)^2}{2}+C=\color{green}{\frac{x^2}{2}+x}+\frac{1}{2}+\color{blue}{C}$$
But on the other hand:
$$\int x+1 \,\mbox{d}x = \int x \,\mbox{d}x+\int 1 \,\mbox{d}x=\color{green}{\frac{x^2}{2}+x}+\color{red}{C}$$
Note that $\color{red}{C}=\frac{1}{2}+\color{blue}{C}$.

Comment: Now if you will differentiate answer then its different by 1/2.

Comment: The derivative of a constant (such as $\tfrac{1}{2}$) is $0$...

Comment: From 1st method after differentiating we get 1/2(2x-5)^2, while from 2nd method after differentiating we get exactly the same function that is given i.e (2x-5)^2

Comment: But this 1/2 is not constant but coefficient here.

Comment: It _is_ a constant (term)...

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\frac{1}{6}(2x-5)^3+c$$ $$=\frac{1}{6}(8x^3-60x^2+150x-125)+c$$ $$=\frac43x^3-10x^2+25x+(c-\frac{125}{6})$$ $$=\frac43x^3-10x^2+25x+C$$

Do you see the change in *c* and *C*?

Comment: Yes.. I understand this. What I really don't understand that from first or second method after differentiating I am getting different function. It suppose to be same

Comment: @Zonnie: The derivatives *are* the same: $$\left[\frac16(2x-5)^3\right]'=\frac16\cdot3(2x-5)^2\cdot2=(2x-5)^2=4x^2-20x+25\;,$$ and $$\left[\frac43x^3-10x^2+25x\right]'=\frac43\cdot3x^2-10\cdot2x+25=4x^2-20x+25\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

Basically,  you have the same answer, the only difference is the constant at the end of the solution.